# Is there a way to improve the TestCafe compilation time?

Tags: testcafe

As of now, the compilation time for our tests takes about 25-30 seconds and then the browser opens.

We don't seem to have that many imports so not sure why it takes so long to compile

```
import config from '../config';
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';
import * as locators from '../helpers/locators';
import { checkout } from '../helpers/commerce';
import { CountryCode } from '@testcafe-for-company-com/helper/graphql/cartService/types';
import { SubscriptionChange } from '@testcafe-for-company-com/helper/graphql/cartService/types/helper/identity/types';
const homePageHelpers = require('../helpers/homePageHelpers');
const sharedHelpers = require('../helpers/shared');
const roles = require('../roles/roles');
import {
  userEmail,
  userEmailAlternate,
  userPassword,
  nonSubUserEmail,
  nonSubUserPassword,
} from '../helpers/constants';
```

Our tsconfig.json file in our typescript project has the following configuration

```
"ts-node": {
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "CommonJS"
    }
  },
```

Is it possible to introduce a different compiler for TestCafe to see if it makes a difference in compilation time? Or is there any recommended course of action to improve the compilation time?

Testcafe has the option to use a different compiler using compilerOptions, what's the recommended way to use a different compiler for example? Example of .testcaferc.js file snippet with the compilerOptions

```
compilerOptions: {
      typescript: {
         customCompilerModulePath: "",
         options: {experimentalDecorators:  true},
         },
      },
```

Here is the output of the debug log of the compilation process
https://upload.disroot.org/r/4AWZqZmm#UmIf+cH8FCeuX/9Jhm7Sd5OAZfj8OLE78BfJuYXUqVc=

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: It is unclear from this code what exactly can lead to long compilation time. It's better to share an example that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Can't share the code because it's part of an internal repository that's only accessible by company employees. Is it possible to have SWC do the compilation instead of typescript in this option- customCompilerModulePath?

Comment: TestCafe supports a compilation of tests written with Typescript only with the 'typescript' module, so SWC is not supported. The `customCompilerModulePath` option is intended to provide a path to a TypeScript module. It can be used if you want to use the TypeScript compiler from your project (or some other specific TypeScript compiler version) instead of the built-in TestCafe TypeScript module. However, this option does not imply that any other compilers can be used except the TypeScript module.

Comment: Got it, thanks. Since some test files in our project compile really fast and others compile slow, is it possible to add in some command to TestCafe to show what exactly is causing the slow compilation time? Using export DEBUG="testcafe:*,hammerhead:*" shows the testcafe:compiler:typescript output but not much can be interpreted from it. Or do you have any possible recommendations on how to improve compilation speed based on your knowledge?

Comment: TestCafe cannot create any other logs except the `DEBUG` log you mentioned. Unfortunately, the information you shared is insufficient to give recommendations. Based on my knowledge, I can refer to the [https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/4054](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/4054) issue and try to search the problem in page model imports in your test files. However, you mentioned that you do not have a lot of imports, but at this moment, it's the only assumption.

Comment: Thanks Alex. We figured out that the issue is coming from one particular imported file. Is there a way to have TestCafe compiler omit the file at the compilation process?

Comment: TestCafe cannot ignore the imported file. Maybe precompiling the `ts` file and importing from 'js' would be a solution. However, without an example, it's difficult to give any recommendations.